# Python, telebot: Error: "message can't be deleted for everyone"

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telebot

I'm building a telegram bot which sends three dices with `bot.send_dice()`. In the code I collect their IDs into a list and then I'm creating new loop to delete every message. `start_message` is a message id which was sent earlier

```
messages = []

time.sleep(0.1)

bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,
                   message_id=start_message.id,)

        time.sleep(0.1)

        for _ in range(3):
            dice_message = bot.send_dice(callback.message.chat.id,
                          emoji="")
            messages.append(dice_message.id)
            time.sleep(6)

        for d in range(3):
            bot.delete_message(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,
                               message_id=messages[d])
```

This code is inside this function:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def main(callback):
    'my code'
```

I'm getting an error:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message can't be deleted for everyone
```

I was expecting that the code would delete all messages in the `messages` list. But it didn't. I tried deleting `time.sleep(time)` lines from my code, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage):

> A dice message in a private chat can only be deleted **if it was sent more than 24 hours ago**.